# Dinamically generate / remove text inputs with checkboxes jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm having troubles with the removal of the correct input text boxes once these have been generated.

Basically the code generates a text input when a checkbox is selected. The generated text input contains the value of the selected checkbox. All this works fine as well does the dependency of the checkboxes selection.

Where I need help is to remove the actual input that contains the value of the de-selected checkbox. right now the one removes is always the last input box instead of the one corresponding to the checkbox being clicked.

The second problem is the following. The checkboxes are organized in pairs. but you can only select one checkbox per pair, this works fine, but I go from one checkbox to the other and the previous is automatically unchecked the input box has to be removed as well.

Here is the working code:

```js
$(function() {
   // Moneyline Visitor
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
  var arrmlv = $("#mlv").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
        $('#mlv').change(function () {
            if ($('#mlv').is(':checked')) {
                $('<input type="text" id="p_scnt'+ i +'" class="p_scnt'+ i +'" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="'+ arrmlv +'" placeholder="No Disponible" />').appendTo(scntDiv);
             i++;   
    $("input[name='rlo']").attr("disabled", true);
    $("input[name='rlu']").attr("disabled", true);
    $("input[name='mll']").prop('checked', false);
            } else if ($('#mlv').not(':checked')) {
   i--;
   $("input[name='rlo']").attr("disabled", false);
            $("input[name='rlu']").attr("disabled", false);
            $('.p_scnt'+ i +'').remove();
            }
         });   
   // Moneyline Local
  var arrmll = $("#mll").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
        $('#mll').change(function () {
            if ($('#mll').is(':checked')) {
                $('<input type="text" id="p_scnt'+ i +'" class="p_scnt'+ i +'" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="'+ arrmll +'" placeholder="No Disponible" />').appendTo(scntDiv);
             i++;   
    $("input[name='rlo']").attr("disabled", true);
    $("input[name='rlu']").attr("disabled", true);
    $("input[name='mlv']").prop('checked', false);
            } else if ($('#mll').not(':checked')) {
   i--;
            $("input[name='rlo']").attr("disabled", false);
            $("input[name='rlu']").attr("disabled", false);
            $('.p_scnt'+ i +'').remove();
            }
         });    
   // Runline Over
  var arrrlo = $("#rlo").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
        $('#rlo').change(function () {
            if ($('#rlo').is(':checked')) {
                $('<input type="text" id="p_scnt'+ i +'" class="p_scnt'+ i +'" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="'+ arrrlo +'" placeholder="No Disponible" />').appendTo(scntDiv);
             i++;   
             $("input[name='mlv']").attr("disabled", true);
    $("input[name='mll']").attr("disabled", true);
    $("input[name='rlu']").prop('checked', false);    
            } else if ($('#rlo').not(':checked')) {
   i--;
            $("input[name='mlv']").attr("disabled", false);
            $("input[name='mll']").attr("disabled", false);   
            $('.p_scnt'+ i +'').remove();
            }
         });    
   // Runline Under
  var arrrlu = $("#rlu").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
        $('#rlu').change(function () {
            if ($('#rlu').is(':checked')) {
                $('<input type="text" id="p_scnt'+ i +'" class="p_scnt'+ i +'" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="'+ arrrlu +'" placeholder="No Disponible" />').appendTo(scntDiv);
             i++; 
             $("input[name='mlv']").attr("disabled", true);
    $("input[name='mll']").attr("disabled", true);
    $("input[name='rlo']").prop('checked', false);    
            } else if ($('#rlu').not(':checked')) {
   i--;
            $("input[name='mlv']").attr("disabled", false);
            $("input[name='mll']").attr("disabled", false);   
            $('.p_scnt'+ i +'').remove();
            }
         });    
   // Over
  var arrov = $("#ov").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
        $('#ov').change(function () {
            if ($('#ov').is(':checked')) {
                $('<input type="text" id="p_scnt'+ i +'" class="p_scnt'+ i +'" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="'+ arrov +'" placeholder="No Disponible" />').appendTo(scntDiv);
             i++;  
    $("input[name='un']").prop('checked', false);    
            } else if ($('#ov').not(':checked')) {
   i--;
            $('.p_scnt'+ i +'').remove();
            }
         });    
   // Under
  var arrun = $("#un").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
        $('#un').change(function () {
            if ($('#un').is(':checked')) {
                $('<input type="text" id="p_scnt'+ i +'" class="p_scnt'+ i +'" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="'+ arrun +'" placeholder="No Disponible" />').appendTo(scntDiv);
             i++; 
    $("input[name='ov']").prop('checked', false);    
            } else if ($('#un').not(':checked')) {
   i--;
            $('.p_scnt'+ i +'').remove();
            }
         });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="mlv" name="mlv" value="+200"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="mll" name="mll" value="-200"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="rlo" name="rlo" value="+100"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="rlu" name="rlu" value="-100"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="ov" name="ov" value="+300"/>

<input type="checkbox" id="un" name="un" value="-300"/>      
</br>

<div id="p_scents">

</div>
```

Comment: try `$("static-parent-container").on("click", "target-dynamic-input", function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem changing the name of the class of the input? If there isn't, you could try this in your change events:

```
$('#mlv').change(function () {
    if ($('#mlv').is(':checked')) {
        $('<input type="text" id="p_scnt'+ i +'" class="p_scntmlv" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="'+ arrmlv +'" placeholder="No Disponible" />').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        $("input[name='rlo']").attr("disabled", true);
        $("input[name='rlu']").attr("disabled", true);
        $("input[name='mll']").prop('checked', false);
        $('.p_scntmll').remove();
    } else if ($('#mlv').not(':checked')) {
        i--;
        $("input[name='rlo']").attr("disabled", false);
        $("input[name='rlu']").attr("disabled", false);
        $('.p_scntmlv').remove();
    }
});
    // Moneyline Local
    var arrmll = $("#mll").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
$('#mll').change(function () {
    if ($('#mll').is(':checked')) {
        $('<input type="text" id="p_scnt'+ i +'" class="p_scntmll" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="'+ arrmll +'" placeholder="No Disponible" />').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;   
        $("input[name='rlo']").attr("disabled", true);
        $("input[name='rlu']").attr("disabled", true);
        $("input[name='mlv']").prop('checked', false);
        $('.p_scntmlv').remove();
    } else if ($('#mll').not(':checked')) {
        i--;
        $("input[name='rlo']").attr("disabled", false);
        $("input[name='rlu']").attr("disabled", false);
        $('.p_scntmll').remove();
    }
});
```

Notice I changed the class of each input to append the ID of the checkbox. That way, when a checkbox is unchecked, you just remove the specific input associated to it. And when a checkbox is checked, you remove the input associated with the checkbox you automatically unchecked.

Comment: Hi all,

Thanks for your help on this. Asyou can see on the link below I have managed to have it running propertly, but now Im facing another chalenge. 

As the 6 check-boxes set is going to be auto-generated with a php/mysql loop, the check-boxes are going to be enumerated as follows e.g. mlv1 for the first loop, mlv2 for the second loop and soon... the same applies for all the check-boxes. I wonder how can I modify my script to apply to every single check-box set??

Any Ideas? Thanks in Advance,
Alex

http://jsfiddle.net/gromikov/23fknm2x/

Comment: @AlexValdez If you have another question, please ask a new one instead of asking in the comments.